# Convert string in struct to []string

Tags: go

I have a `struct` as below:

```golang
type TourData struct {
    ArtistID   int    //artist ID
    RelationID string //key for relations
    City       string
    Country    string
    TourDates  []string
}

type MyRelation struct {
    ID             int                 `json:"id"`
    DatesLocations map[string][]string `json:"datesLocations"`
}
```

which contains this data from a csv file:

```
1,nagoya-japan,Nagoya,Japan,
1,penrose-new_zealand,Penrose,New_Zealand,
1,dunedin-new_zealand,Dunedin,New_Zealand,
2,playa_del_carmen-mexico,Playa Del Carmen,Mexico,
2,papeete-french_polynesia,Papeete,French_Polynesia,
```

MyRelations is populated from an API which contains:

```
"index": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "datesLocations": {
                "dunedin-new_zealand": [
                    "10-02-2020"
                ],
                "nagoya-japan": [
                    "30-01-2019"
                ],
                "penrose-new_zealand": [
                    "07-02-2020"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "datesLocations": {
                "papeete-french_polynesia": [
                    "16-11-2019"
                ],
                "playa_del_carmen-mexico": [
                    "05-12-2019",
                    "06-12-2019",
                    "07-12-2019",
                    "08-12-2019",
                    "09-12-2019"
                ]
            }
        }
```

The dates come from another struct.  The code I have used to populate this struct is as below:

```golang
var oneRecord TourData
    var allRecords []TourData

for _, each := range csvData {
    oneRecord.ArtistID, _ = strconv.Atoi(each[0])
    oneRecord.RelationID = each[1]
    oneRecord.City = each[2]
    oneRecord.Country = each[3]
    oneRecord.TourDates = Relations.Index[oneRecord.ArtistID-1].DatesLocations[each[1]]
    allRecords = append(allRecords, oneRecord)
}
    
jsondata, err := json.Marshal(allRecords) // convert to JSON
json.Unmarshal(jsondata, &TourThings)
```

I need to group all the 1s together then the 2s etc.  I thought to create another struct, and populate from this one but not having much luck - any ideas?

To clarify I would want say TourData.City to equal:

```
[Nagoya,Penrose,Dunedin]
[Playa Del Carmen, Papeete]
```

At the moment if I was to print TourData[0].City I would get Nagoya.

I have tried creating another struct to be populated from the TourData struct with the following fields:

```
type TourDataArrays struct {
    ArtistID  int
    City      []string
    Country   []string
    TourDates [][]string
}
```

and then populate the struct using the code below:

```
var tourRecord TourDataArrays
    var tourRecords []TourDataArrays
    for i := 0; i < len(Relations.Index); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(allRecords); j++ {
            if allRecords[i].ArtistID == i+1 {
                tourRecord.City = append(tourRecord.City, allRecords[j].City)
            }
        }
        tourRecords = append(tourRecords, tourRecord)
    }
```

However this is adding all the cities to one array i.e

[Nagoya, Penrose, Dunedin, Playa Del Carmen, Papeete].

Comment: What do you mean by "group all the 1s together"; do you just want the slice [sorted](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Slice) (ordered by 1 then 2, then 3 etc)?. Where the data comes from does not appear relevant; perhaps give us a sample input/expected output in JSON.

Comment: I have edited my question - is that ok?

Comment: Sorry - your change introduces another undefined type (`TourDataArrays`) along with those already there (`Relations`, `oneRecord` etc). Please aim for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); something [like this](https://go.dev/play/p/oXQBxdHsyP4) (which may already answer your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly you needed to declare city as a string array as well. (And Country to go with it).

Check out this solution : https://go.dev/play/p/osgkbfWV3c5

Note I have not deduped country and derived city and country from one field in the Json.

Comment: Thank you that is so much more concise than what I was doing.  I feel a bit like give an inch take a ruler here but would it then be possible to sort the array by country as the list is currently in a random order?

Comment: Just to give some clarification as to the end goal I want to create a html table which will list country, city and dates ordered by country.

Comment: And another thing I'm trying to unmarshal from an API but keep getting this error panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.MyRelation any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried sorting it? The sort (https://pkg.go.dev/sort@go1.17.7) package provides functions for that. Reg your  unmarshal error, cannot really say anything unless the code is seen. please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I think the question would be overly long if I posted that code in too!  I've managed to do something which is probably hodge podge but I can access the elements in the struct now just need to figure out a way of creating a table from it.  Thank you again for all your time :)